# How to move color scale labels to middle of colored fields in matplotlib/xarray?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, categorical-data, python-xarray

I have a heatmap with discrete values (=categories/factors), created as follows:

```
import xarray
dats =  xarray.DataArray([[2,4,3,5,1],[8,4,5,3,2], [9,3,4,4,1]])
dats.plot(levels=range(0, 11, 1), cmap='Blues')
```

[image: Heatmap]

I would like to move the numbers at the color scale / legend to the middle of the respective field. I (and colleagues) find their position at the intersection of fields a bit misleading, especially considering that the ticks at the x-axis in the heatmap itself are in the very middle of the fields.

How can I move those values at the color scale up to the middle of the fields (and cut off the 10, which is not a value in the data set)?

Comment: To be clear, the `levels` argument in `DataArray.plot` is intended for making continuous variables discrete, not to handle categorical variables. I opened a GitHub issue to discuss adding direct support for categorical plotting: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/920

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do think that handling categorical variables is something were the PyData stack needs improving. Matplotlib and friends rather focused on floats, I think. So I would be very glad to see this added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you have to use matplotlib directly:

```
import xarray
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
dats =  xarray.DataArray([[2,4,3,5,1],[8,4,5,3,2], [9,3,4,4,1]])
qm = dats.plot(levels=range(0, 11, 1), cmap='Blues', add_colorbar = False)

cbar = plt.colorbar(qm)
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
for j in range(0, 10, 1):
    cbar.ax.text(.5, (j+.5) / 10., j, ha='center', va='center', color='red')
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().labelpad = 15

plt.show()
```

[image]